# Delete all records in All subscribers that where created today with a query?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I accidentally imported records to All subscribers, where I only should have updated.
Is there a query I could use to delete the records that where created? I also updated some and they are ok as they are.

Ideas are do very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

SFMC doesn't "delete" records in the traditional way - however you can flag subscribers for deletion; see: [**Subscribers**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/subscribers1/): Subscriber Status.

You could build a Query to select the affected records from the [**Subscribers View**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_subscribers/), as follows:

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey
,'Deleted' as 'Status'
FROM [_Subscribers]
WHERE DateJoined = **YourDateHere**
```

Insert that data into a Data Extension, then Export it, and then [**Import**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/) it into the AllSubscribers List.

Given how damaging this action could be to your subscriber database - I suggest exporting and reviewing the selected subscribers before importing the Deleted status into AllSubscribers.

Comment: Thank you Cameron. That sounds scary. I have hundreds of thousand new records... But that is probably the only way. There is no other way to reset or revert?

Comment: Guys! I have a backup of all subscribers, on a ftp out of direct access. What if I import it to a data extension and then delete ALL subscribers from the All Subscribers list, and then import my Data extensrion to it? Would the history snd all be preserved or does this reset all subscribers?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete Subscribers with a Query Activity.

But there is another way to delete them in an Enterprise 2.0 account:

1. Create a List (e.g. SubscribersToDelete) in the *parent* Business Unit.
2. Identify the subscribers to delete and export them to a file.  At a minimum you need columns for SubscriberKey and any other required Profile Attributes.
3. Import the file into the list in the *parent* Business Unit.
4. Upon successful import, delete the List and check the box to delete the Subscribers from All Subscribers.